# php rand в цикле while

Tags: php, циклы, while

Есть такой кусочек кода:

```
$repeat = 1;
while ($repeat == 1) {
    $temprand = rand(0, $vidc);
    if (!in_array($temprand, $vid)) {
      if ($temprand != 0) {
      echo $temprand;
      $repeat = 0;
      } else {
        $ttt = rand(0, $vidc);
        if ($ttt == 0) {
          echo "Ended";
          $repeat = 0;
        }
      }
    }
};
```

Где $vidc = 3.
А $vid равен массиву (1) или (1, 2), или (1, 3) или (1, 2, 3)
Его цель - генерировать случайное число от 1 до 3 так, чтобы не было повторений. То есть если выпадает 1, второй раз 1 выпасть не может. 0 используется для закрытия цикла, при выпадании 0 два раза цикл обрывается. Умнее ничего не придумал... Из-за этого, цикл может отработать 1, 2 и пропустить 3, или отработать 1, и пропустить 2, 3. Подскажите, есть ли более простой способ сделать задуманное?

Comment: сделайте массив [1,2,3], перемешайте shuffle() и получите последовательность?

Comment: не выйдет)) там много всего до этого, и этот массив будет достигать 10000, и постоянно расти, мне некуда эту последовательность потом записывать

Comment: *этот массив будет достигать 10000,* - видимо я совсем ничего не понял - там же неповторяющиеся 1,2,3 ?

Comment: да я для примера привел))) массив будет пополняться каждый день, все больше и больше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Один из вариантов не повторяющихся рандомных значений можно построить таким образом

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['arr']) && !isset($_SESSION['bool'])) {
    $_SESSION['arr'] = range(1, 10);
}

$arr = &$_SESSION['arr'];

if (is_array($arr)) {
    $key = array_rand($arr);
    echo $arr[$key];
    unset($arr[$key]);
}

if (count($_SESSION['arr']) < 1) {
    unset($_SESSION['arr']);
    $_SESSION['bool'] = true;
}
```

> **UPD:** Дописал вариант без использования сессий

```
$file = 'numbers.txt';
$numbers = file_exists($file) 
    ? file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) 
    : range(1, 10);

if (!empty($numbers)) {
    shuffle($numbers);
    echo $numbers[0];
    unset($numbers[0]);
    file_put_contents($file, join(PHP_EOL, $numbers));
}
```

Comment: я так понял тут выбор только из 9 значений? А если мне нужно 10000?

Comment: @Paul Wall подправил для 10K.

Comment: то есть я запускаю код, он нормально генерируется, а затем мы убиваем сессию, и по сути, в следующий раз, когда запускаем, этот все начнется с начала, без запоминания уже выведенных чисел?

Comment: @Paul Wall в сессию идёт запись для демонстрации и понимания работы скрипта. Для ваших нужд используйте запись в текст.файл, или в базу.

Comment: вроде мысль понял, создаю переменную массив в 10000,  затем эту переменную перебираю array_rand, затем через unset удаляю выпавшее число из этого массива, и слежу выполнение через count, когда там ничего не остается код останавливается, поправтье если не то сказал

Comment: @Paul Wall _когда там ничего не остается код останавливается_ -- когда массив станет пустой, генерация случайных значений не остановится, а начнётся заново.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68478/discussion-between--and-paul-wall).